# Android NDK: ERROR:src/main/jni/Android.mk:opencv_java: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

#opencv
OPENCVROOT := C:\OpenCV-2.4.9-android-sdk
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES :=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include $(OPENCVROOT)/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_aamirhussain_ndkopencvtest1_OpencvNativeClass.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
LOCAL_MODULE := MyOpencvLibs

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


Android NDK: ERROR:src/main/jni/Android.mk:opencv_java: LOCAL_SRC_FILES    points to a missing file
```

i checked .cpp file path is also correct . but unable to figureout where actual the problem is .

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the cpp is really on the right place, add this at the beginning of you Android.mk file, as this is required according to the documentation:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
```

For further explanation, see here: [Android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html), under Basics section.